# trouble in opening csproj file in vs 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ibm-mobilefirst

Hello i have developed an winodwsphone8 application in ibm Mobilefirst.
I cant able to open the csproj generated from the ibm tool.I have installed visual studio 2015 and sdk and my os is winodws 10 .when opening it shows error as **operation cancelled** .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing an error that says "Duplicated source project item...". If yes, then it is due to a bug in Visual Studio 2015. See https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1689126/duplicated-source-project-item-error

You can use Visual Studio 2013 or Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 where the issue has been fixed.

Comment: no cant able to open the .csproj itself while loading itself it shows operation cancelled popup

Comment: Which version of MFP are you using ? Can you share the VS project.